SSH from iPhone into RPi 2B on the go
I have a RPi 2B and Zero W. When I’m on the go I want to ssh into the 2B but I have no WiFi adapter. So I thought I can connect the 2B and the Zero using a Ethernet cable and adapter (for the Zero). Then I connect the Zero to my Phones hotspot - Will the Zero automatically connect to the hotspot again after it was disconnected when ssid and pswd stay the same? - and share/bridge the connection to the 2B so I can ssh into the 2B?
If that is possible, how? Please tell me.
I’m relatively new to all this networking so please forgive me when I don’t instantly understand something.
I tried just straight forward connecting and looking for an ip from the 2B. But as I thought it didn’t work that way.

See Tour to see how this site works
and How do I ask a good question?

The Pi Zero W has one network interface. It can connect to ONE thing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
